# Understanding Scala use of abstract types and Classes

Tags: scala, abstract-type

The next code does not compile. Why can't `Santorin`  eat `HorseFood`? `Tornado` is declared as a new `Horse`, and `Horse` is a subtype of `Animal`, yet it can "eat" `HorseFood`.

```
import scala.io.StdIn._
import util._


class Food

abstract class Animal
{
    type SuitableFood <: Food
    def eat(food: SuitableFood)
}

class Grass extends Food  /*extends meaning should be "more specific than*/
class Fish extends Food
class HorseFood extends Grass

class Cow extends Animal
{
    type SuitableFood = Grass
    override def eat(food: SuitableFood) = {}
}

class Horse extends Animal
{
  type SuitableFood = Grass
  override def eat(food: SuitableFood) = {}
}

class Whale extends Animal
{
    type SuitableFood = Fish
    override def eat(food: SuitableFood) = {}

}

object abstractExample1 {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val bessy: Animal = new Cow
    println("bessy = " + bessy)
    bessy eat (new Grass).asInstanceOf[bessy.SuitableFood]
     /*added this line because of a great answer someone posted for this questions but he deleted*/

    val willie: Animal = new Whale
    println("willie = " + willie)

    val santorin: Animal = new Horse
    println("santorin = " + santorin)

    val tornado = new Horse
    tornado eat new HorseFood

    print("tornado = " + tornado)
    santorin.eat(new HorseFood)

  }

}
```

Shouldn't this be automatically be allowed (as `Horse` extends `Animal`)? Why isn't it?

Notice that `Tornado`, as declared can eat `HorseFood` that extends `Grass`, and that the food parameter at the class `Horse` is `Grass`.

Is there a problem here with the `=` ? I mean, `SuitableFood` is exactly `Grass` and not a class `C` extension of `Grass`.

Comment: why you have not declared this? - val tornado: Animal = new Horse

Comment: I did and tornado could not eat HorseFood anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Santorin is an `Animal` not a `Horse` so it 'eats' 'type' not `HorseFood`. This is because reference to it is for `Animal`.
Change  `val santorin: Animal = new Horse`
to  `val santorin: Horse = new Horse`
and it would work fine

Comment: I know how the code could compile. It is just some behavior with inheritance seemed to be a little bit strange for me.

Comment: It's more comprehensible if you think in logical terms instead of code terms. Here you have created a new Horse but told the compiler that it's an 'Animal'. So it only expects behaviour of an 'Animal' not a 'Horse'.

Comment: As for 'tornado' you have not explicitly given any type for it so scala provides it implicitly as the class type whose object is created i.e Horse.

Answer (score 1):

`Animal#SuitableFood` is subtype of `Food`

```
implicitly[Animal#SuitableFood <:< Food]
```

Each instance of `Horse` assigned to `Animal`-typed `val` contains brand new `SuitableFood` type which is subtype of `Animal#SuitableFood`

```
val santorin: Animal = new Horse
val santorin2: Animal = new Horse

implicitly[santorin.SuitableFood <:< Animal#SuitableFood]
implicitly[santorin2.SuitableFood <:< Animal#SuitableFood]
implicitly[santorin.SuitableFood =:= santorin2.SuitableFood] //-- fails
//                     ^^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^^
//                       these types are different
implicitly[santorin.SuitableFood =:= Grass] // -- fails

val tornado = new Horse
val tornado2 = new Horse

implicitly[tornado.SuitableFood =:= tornado2.SuitableFood] // compiles!
//                     ^^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^^
//                               Grass =:= Grass

implicitly[tornado.SuitableFood =:= Grass] // compiles
```

Signature of `eat` method for `santorin: Animal` will be the following:

```
def eat(food: santorin.SuitableFood) // SuitableFood is path-dependent
```

*`santorin.SuitableFood` is a subtype of both `Food` and `Animal#SuitableFood`*

`HorseFood` is subtype of `Food` and `Grass` but not subtype of `santorin.SuitableFood` or `Animal#SuitableFood`

```
implicitly[HorseFood <:< Food]
implicitly[HorseFood <:< Grass]
implicitly[HorseFood <:< santorin.SuitableFood]//  -- fails
implicitly[HorseFood <:< Animal#SuitableFood]//  -- fails
```

That's why calling method `eat` on `HorseFood` is failing as well. Because `HorseFood` is not subtype of `santorin.SuitableFood`.

And that's why following works:

```
santorin.eat((new HorseFood).asInstanceOf[santorin.SuitableFood])
```

Comment: can you please explain this, val willie: Animal = new Whale?

Comment: this was just some code I added to see the behavior of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [variance](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html).

Your classes are invariant. It means `Animal` with `SuitableFood <: Food` can't be an `Animal` with `SuitableFood = HorseFood`.

You can see it if you rewrite your classes to generic-like style:

```
trait Food
class Grass extends Food
class HorseFood extends Grass

abstract class Animal[SuitableFood <: Food] {
    def eat(food: SuitableFood)
}

val animal1: Animal[HorseFood] = null
//the next line doesn't compile because Animal[HorseFood] isn't a subclass of Animal[Food]
val animal2: Animal[Food] = animal1
```

So an animal who can eat `Food` can't eat `HorseFood`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Generic classes can be variant. How can a normal non generic class be variant or not?

Comment: This is an roughly similar example for clear understanding. When you use an object of type Anymal compiler doesn't now what type is SuitableFood. And becouse your function `eat` isn't covariant, it can receive only parameter of exact type SuitableFood (whitch is unknown)

Comment: If you rewrite your code to generics it will be obvious that Animal with SuitableFood <: Food can't be an Animal with SuitableFood = HorseFood